# Implementing Queue of Pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, queue

I am trying to implement 8-puzzle (BFS) using two queues of pointers. I am having trouble adding untraveled nodes to the open list. Where I am going wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>     
#include <algorithm>    
#include <vector>       
#include <queue>
using namespace std;
class Node {
public:
    vector<Node> children;
    vector<int> puzzle;
    vector<int> goal = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0};
    Node *parent;

    Node(vector<int> _puzzle, Node *_parent){
        puzzle=_puzzle;
        parent=_parent;
    }

    void printPuzzle() {
        int count = 0;
        for (auto i: puzzle) {
            if ( count % 3 == 0)
                std::cout << std::endl;
            std::cout << i << ' ';
            count++;   
        }
    }

    int findZero(){
        std::vector<int>::iterator it;
        it = find (puzzle.begin(), puzzle.end(), 0);
        auto z = std::distance(puzzle.begin(), it);
        return (int)z;
    }

    bool isGoal(){
        bool goalFound = false;
        if(puzzle == goal)
            goalFound = true;
        return goalFound;
    }

    void moveUp(){
        int zPos = findZero();
        vector<int> temp = puzzle;
        if ( zPos != 0 && zPos != 1 && zPos != 2 )
            std::swap(temp[zPos], temp[zPos-3]);
        Node child = Node(temp, this);
        children.push_back(child);        
    }

    void moveDown(){
        int zPos = findZero();
        vector<int> temp = puzzle;
        if ( zPos != 6 && zPos != 7 && zPos != 8 )
            std::swap(temp[zPos], temp[zPos+3]);
        Node child = Node(temp, this);
        children.push_back(child); 
    }

    void moveRight(){
        int zPos = findZero();
        vector<int> temp = puzzle;
        if ( zPos != 2 && zPos != 5 && zPos != 8 )
            std::swap(temp[zPos], temp[zPos+1]);
        Node child = Node(temp, this);
        children.push_back(child);
    }

    void moveLeft(){ 
        int zPos = findZero();
        vector<int> temp = puzzle;
        if ( zPos != 0 && zPos != 3 && zPos != 6 )
        std::swap(temp[zPos], temp[zPos-1]);
        Node child = Node(temp, this);
        children.push_back(child); 
    }

    bool isSamePuzzle(vector<int> p){
        bool samePuzzle = false;
        if(puzzle == p)
        samePuzzle =  true;
        return samePuzzle;

    }
};


bool contains(std::queue<Node*> q, Node n){
    bool exist = false;
    while (!q.empty()){
        cout << endl;
        if (q.front()->puzzle == n.puzzle)
        exist = true;
        q.pop();
    }
    return exist;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> initial;
    initial.push_back(2);
    initial.push_back(1);
    initial.push_back(3);
    initial.push_back(4);
    initial.push_back(0);
    initial.push_back(6);
    initial.push_back(7);
    initial.push_back(5);
    initial.push_back(8);
    Node init = Node(initial, NULL);
    std::queue<Node*> openList;
    std::queue<Node*> closedList;
    openList.push(&init);
    bool goalFound = false;
    while(!openList.empty() && !goalFound){
        Node* currentNode = openList.front();
        closedList.push(currentNode);
        cout << "open list size " << openList.size() <<endl;
        cout << "closed list size " << closedList.size() <<endl;
        openList.pop();
        currentNode->moveUp();
        currentNode->moveDown();
        currentNode->moveRight();
        currentNode->moveLeft();

        for (auto i: currentNode->children){
            Node currentChild = i;
            if (currentChild.isGoal()){
                std::cout << "Goal Found." << endl;
                goalFound = true;                
            }
            if (!contains(openList, currentChild) && !contains(closedList, currentChild))
                openList.push(&currentChild);             
        }
    }
}
```

This seems to be the problematic bit:

```
            if (!contains(openList, currentChild) && !contains(closedList, 
 currentChild))
            openList.push(&currentChild);
```

After adding one or two nodes to the open list, the program crashes. When I print out the puzzle in the open list I see that there is some garbage value at the beginning followed by the actual pluzzle.

Comment: Spend some time thinking about the lifetime of `currentChild` and how good an idea it is store a pointer to it.

Comment: `for (auto i: currentNode->children){  Node* currentChild = &i;  /***/  }`   something like this?

Comment: @molbdnilo Hi. I think I have solved the issue by making children in the Node class a vector of node pointers. Is this the hint you were trying to give me?

Answer (score 0):

I pasted your code into my IDE and ran it through my debugger. What I see happening here is when you are going through your while loop on its 2<sup>nd</sup> iteration; it prints the 2 lines of code, it pops from openList, it calls and executes `moveUp()` but when it goes into `moveDown()` is where it crashes.

It crashes on this line:

```
std::swap( temp[zPos], temp[zPos+3] );
```

You might want to check this line of code in your debugger while stepping through your while loop checking your variables and containers here to see if they have valid information; also check to see if you're not `exceeding` the `bound` of your `container`. You might also want to check to see if the `memory` is still valid after calling `swap` from the previous call to `moveUp()`.

Not during the 1<sup>st</sup> call to `moveDown()` but the on the 2<sup>nd</sup> call is where you are setting `temp` to be equal to `puzzle` the problem here is that `puzzle` has a value or size of `0`. So when you try to call `std::swap` on `temp[zPos]` & `temp[zPos+3]` the indexes are invalid since `temp` has `size = 0`.

Comment: I think the reason that might be happening is because of the lifetime of currentChild as mentioned by @molbdino in the comments. Since the currentChild gets destroyed after while loop a garbage values gets pushed into the current node and when it tries to swap the puzzle the sizes don't match.

Comment: @pranavinani I'm thinking the same too; I was just giving the OP the guidance of where to look into the debugger to find the root cause of the crash.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem of your program is, that you push a pointer to a local variable on your open list. The variable `currentChild` will be destroyed once the scope is left (so as soon as you either go into the next iteration of the loop or leave the loop), and then the pointer points to unused/junk memory.

However, you will encounter similar problems at other places, as you can't reliably save pointers to any Node in the `vector<Node>` list. This is due to the fact that the `std::vector` class will destroy/copy everything inside it whenever it reaches a certain size for the first time, which will invalidate any pointer to anything inside it. So either you save *only* pointers to Nodes in all cointainers (`queue` and `vector`, so only pointers gets destroyed/copied), or you don't save *any* pointer to Nodes, but only Nodes itself - whatever suites you the best.

Comment: I think I fixed that by making the the followin change
`vector<Node> children;`  
 and making child nodes pointers.. the program runs fine and I can access the puzzles in each node. However, when i try to look up the parents of nodes in the closed list I get a segmentation fault. But i can print out the parent state puzzles of open list just fine. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: @pranavinani Hard to tell without seeing the updated code, but most likely your closed list still contains pointers to something that has already been destroyed or moved to some other location. (segmentation fault is given to you if you try to access freed memory) Propably, one of your vectors grows too large and reallocates its memory, invalidating every pointer to anything iside it along the way. But I can't do much more than guessing without seeing what your code looks like after your changes :/

Comment: I don't think I can change the code here..since this relates to a different question. Right?

Comment: @pranavinani I... guess so. To be honest, I'm pretty new to stackoverflow (at least as a registered member) and don't know what is allowed or not. You could upload your code at a page like pastebin and send me the link, or add it to your question as an edit or so. As I said, I don't really know much about the rules of this site yet :/

Comment: @pranavinani The problem is, that your front element in the closed list is the first element that was ever in the open list - which is your init Node, which doesn't have a parent (parent is set to NULL). Depending on what you want (I'm not quite familar with what the 8-Puzzle actually is) you might want to use stack instead of queue for the closed list, so you can get the last inserted Node instead of the first one?

Comment: Thank you! I do not need to change anything. My code works fine. the init node pointing to the null pointer is what I want from the program. It will help me trace back the solution once I find it. Just checked, all other nodes in the closed list are able to point to their respective parent nodes. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the code by making children a vector of Node pointers like so:

```
vector<Node*> children;
```

and each child a node pointer:

```
Node* child = new Node(temp, this);
```